# Excel formula to extract 90 character sentence text (without breaking word) from a long paragraph

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have very long paragraphs in column A in excel. Example entry in cell A1 is mentioned below:

> "The Essential Accessory  • Adds comfort and safety for
> passengers by offering back support and also helps carry luggage
> • Built for the long haul from high strength steel and
> heavy-duty mounting brackets  • Uses stock mounting points for a
> no fabrication installation  Includes: Sissy Bar, Hardware, Standard
> Freedom Sissy Bar Pad (Freedom pad matches Cobra's Freedom and
> Smoothee seats)  Also Available (Sold Separately): 1. Jumbo Freedom
> Pad 2. Replacement Standard Freedom Pad 3. Fluted Backrest Insert 4.
> Swept Backrest Insert"

I would like to pull up to 90 character complete sentence text (without breaking word) in B1 cell and remaining 90 character complete sentence text (without breaking word) in C1 cell. I would like to utilize value from B1 and C1 into description lines of google text ads.

Is there anyone who can provide me excel formulas or VBA script who would pull that data? For some reason LEFT function with 90 character condition is pulling sentence, but the last word is not a complete word (its breaking).

I tried the below formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,90)
```

***which give me this value***: The Essential Accessory • Adds comfort and safety for passengers by offering back s

***However, i exactly need***: "The Essential Accessory • Adds comfort and safety for passengers by offering back" which is a complete sentence.

***And in C1 I want this value***: "support and also helps carry luggage • Built for the long haul from high strength"

Comment: *which is a complete sentence.* No it's not. It's a complete word but the sentence ends with `carry luggage`

Comment: Will the bullet character always be part of the text?

Comment: In your question the **exactly need** result is not  90 character. The function gives this: `"The Essential Accessory • Adds comfort and safety for passengers by offering back support`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the **FIRST** line up to a maximum of 90 characters, and you have Microsoft 365, you can use this formula:

```
=TRIM(INDEX(LET(a,LEFT(A1,SEQUENCE(25,,91,-1)),b, FILTER(a,RIGHT(a)=" "),b),1))
```

[image]

If you want to parse the entire text, here is a VBA macro that uses Regular Expressions to parse the data into appropriate row lengths.

As written, it writes the results below the selected cell(s) in separate cells, but you can change this for your requirements.

I have added a column showing the line lengths, but that is not part of the macro.

```
Option Explicit
Sub WordWrap()
'requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'Wraps at W characters, but will allow overflow if a word is longer than W
Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
Dim str As String
Dim W As Long
Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range
Dim mBox As Long
Dim I As Long
'with offset as 1, split data will be below original data
'with offset = 0, split data will replace original data
Const lDestOffset As Long = 1

Set rSrc = Selection
    If rSrc.Rows.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox ("You may only select" & vbLf & " Data in One (1) Row")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Set RE = New RegExp
    RE.Global = True
W = InputBox("Maximum characters in a Line: ", , 72)
    If W < 1 Then W = 79
For Each C In rSrc
str = C.Value
'remove all line feeds and nbsp
    RE.Pattern = "[\xA0\r\n\s]+"
    str = RE.Replace(str, " ")
    RE.Pattern = "\S.{0," & W - 1 & "}(?=\s|$)|\S{" & W & ",}"
    Debug.Print RE.Pattern
If RE.Test(str) = True Then
    Set MC = RE.Execute(str)
'see if there is enough room
I = lDestOffset + 1
Do Until I > MC.Count + lDestOffset
    If Len(C(I, 1)) <> 0 Then
        mBox = MsgBox("Data in " & C(I, 1).Address & " will be erased if you contine", vbOKCancel)
        If mBox = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    End If
I = I + 1
Loop

    I = lDestOffset
    For Each M In MC
        C.Offset(I, 0).Value = M
        I = I + 1
    Next M
End If
Next C
Set RE = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfield, The VBA code is throwing error "Compile error: User-defined type not defined". I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: @AshokPatidar What line returns the error?  Did you set the reference as instructed? Do you want the entire paragraph parsed or do you just want the first line returned?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Office 365, this formula should work:

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(LET(spacePos,IFERROR(UNIQUE(FIND(" ",A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))),-1),IF(spacePos<=90,spacePos,-1))))
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I think I may have misinterpreted the question and overdid it a bit.

Comment: Hi Jkpieterse, Unfortunately, I am using Excel 2007. Do you have any formula suggestion that would work on Excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the first 90 use

`=TEXTBEFORE(LEFT(A1,91)," ",-1)`

if you want the text divided into chops of 90 character sentences of whole words,you could try the following using Office 365:

```
=LET(a,90,
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(INT(LEN(A1)/a)+2),
     LAMBDA(x, y,
            LET(z,LEN(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,x)),
VSTACK(x,
       IF(LEN(z)=LEN(A1),
          "",
          TEXTBEFORE( LEFT(
                           SUBSTITUTE(A1&" ",                                
                                      IF(LEN(z)=1,
                                         "",
                                         TEXTJOIN(" ",1,x)&" "),
                                      ""),
                           a+1),
                      " ",
                      -1)))))),
     1))
```

Comment: Or judging by jkpieterse's respons and looking back at your post, did you only wanted to retrieve the first sentence, not the following?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses extra cells to store the position of the first character for each "sentence" according to your example:

In B1 and copy with excel to C1 D1 etc.:

```
=IFERROR(MID($A$1,B2,C2-B2),RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-B2+1))
```

Helping cell B2 = 1

Helping cell in B3 and copy with excel to C3 D3 etc.:

```
=+FIND(" ",$A$1,90+B2)+1
```

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXgp3.png)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the formula is also taking breaking words (not stopping on completed word).